# ¿Cómo puedo asignar el peso de la nota para cada variable? no se como hacerlo para que me salga correcto

Tags: java, algoritmos

Leer dos valores de punto flotante de doble precisión A y B, correspondiente a dos notas de estudiantes. Luego de esto, calcular el promedio de los estudiantes, considerando que el peso de la nota A es 3.5 y el peso de la nota B es 7.5. Cada nota puede ser de cero a diez, siempre con un dígito después del punto decimal.

*****MI CODIGO*****

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      double A, B, PROMEDIO;
      Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
      A = key.nextDouble();
      B = key.nextDouble();
      PROMEDIO = (A+B)/2;
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000");
      System.out.println("Media = "+df.format(PROMEDIO));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Disculpa pero, además de lo que te comenta gbianchi, no se entiende bien cuál es tu problema y qué pasa con tu código. Por favor, edita la pregunta, sigue los consejos que te dan y trata de explicar bien qué quieres que pasa, qué está pasando y con qué datos estás probando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar respuesta a la pregunta, comienzo por compartir un enlace donde explican a detalle como es la fórmula para sacar el promedio de las notas contando con que las notas tienen un porcentaje diferente.

[Tutorial notas con porcentajes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBSfWr9oVFM)

Tambien comparto otra ruta en caso tal de que la solución a aportar sea calcular el promedio de notas con pesos (Calcular el promedio ponderado)

[Calcular el promedio ponderado](https://es.wikihow.com/calcular-el-promedio-ponderado)

Ahora si, dejo mi aporte de como podrías hacer la funcionalidad.

***Sacando el promedio con porcentajes***

```
public class PromedioNotasPorcentaje {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // Declaramos las variables
            double notaA;
            double notaB;
            double promedio;
            // Declaramos e inicializamos los valores de los porcentajes de cada nota
            double porcentajeA = 3.5/100; // Porcentaje Nota A 3.5% dividido entre 100 es 0.035
            double porcentajeB = 7.5/100; // Prcentaje Nota B 7.5% dividido entre 100 es 0.075

            Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

            notaA = key.nextDouble();
            notaB = key.nextDouble();

            /**
             * Para el calculo del promedio se multiplica la nota con su respectivo porcentaje
             * Luego se suman los resultados y ese es el promedio.
             */
            promedio = (notaA * porcentajeA) + (notaB * porcentajeB);

            System.out.println("Media = " + promedio);
            key.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Sacando el promedio ponderado es decir con pesos***

```
public class PromedioNotasPeso {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // Declaramos las variables
            double notaA;
            double notaB;
            double promedio;
            // Declaramos e inicializamos los valores de los porcentajes de cada nota
            double pesoA = 3.5;
            double pesoB = 7.5;
            double sumaPesos = pesoA + pesoB;

            Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

            notaA = key.nextDouble();
            notaB = key.nextDouble();

            /**
             * Si la suma de los pesos es mayor a 1, la formula a aplicar es ((nota1*peso1)+(notaN*pesoN))/(peso1+pesoN)
             * Si la suma de los pesos es 1, la formula a aplicar es (nota1*peso1)+(notaN*pesoN)
             */
            if (sumaPesos > 1d) {
                promedio = ((notaA * pesoA) + (notaB * pesoB))/(pesoA + pesoB);             
            } else if(sumaPesos == 1d) {
                promedio = (notaA * pesoA) + (notaB * pesoB);
            }

            /**
             * Se hace que imprima siempre el promedio con 1 decimal 
             */

            /*
             * alternativa 1 con DecimalFormat
             */
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
            System.out.println("Media = " + df.format(promedio));

            /*
             * Alternativa 2 con operaciones matematicas
             * usando el Math.round
             */
            promedio = Math.round(promedio * 10) / 10d;
            System.out.println("Media = " + promedio);

            /*
             * Alternativa 3 con BigDecimal
             */
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(promedio).setScale(1, RoundingMode.UP);
            promedio = bigDecimal.doubleValue();
            System.out.println("Media = " + promedio);

            key.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Me parece que está mal tu forma de hallar el promedio de acuerdo a los pesos

Comment: puedes validar los resultados usando páginas como la siguiente: https://www.iue.edu.co/portal/calcula-tu-nota/ Lo único es que esta página solo permite en los porcentajes valores enteros

Comment: Lo digo porque cuando hablan de pesos, ejemplo nota 1 con peso  2, nota 2 con peso 3, el promedio se halla con la fórmula: (nota1*2 +nota2*3)/5; es decir (nota1*peso1+nota2*peso2)/(peso1+peso2)

Comment: Estas equivocado, La fórmula real es Peso(porcentaje) multiplicado por la nota sacada y dividida en 100. Es decir (nota1*porcentajeNota1/100) y si se desea sacar el promedio de varias notas se aplica esa misma fórmula a cada nota y luego se suman los resultados obtenidos. Puedes observar el enlace que compartí. Recordar que el 100 hace referecia al 100% que es el valor definitivo

Comment: Creo que estamos discutiendo en vano, porque podemos tener razón los 2; te explico: la fórmula que usas es verdadero cuando te indican que el peso está dado en función a 100, pero para ello te deben dar el total de pesos y que la suma sea 100. En mi caso es una fórmula universal para promedios de notas: promedio= (nota1*peso1+...+notaN*pesoN)/(peso1+peso2+...+pesoN).

Comment: Entonces podemos formularla de ambas formas, lo que si veo es que si sumamos 3.5 + 7.5 va a dar como resultado 11 que eso podría ser un 110% o se consideraría el 11 como el 100% de las notas?

Comment: Te invito a que pruebes los resultados con una calculadora probando 2 notas cualquiera entre 0 y 10 y me indiques cual es el promedio que obtienes usando ambas fórmulas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127029/discussion-between-joshin-and-jorge-gomez).

Comment: Anexé las 2 formas en caso tal de algo, ps allí está. Un enlace tutorial para el primer caso que es el promedio con porcentajes y el ejemplo en java o el segundo caso con un enlace guía para el promedio ponderado, que es la opción que me mencionabas y el ejemplo al final en java